# Windows 2008R2 dns loopback best practices, setup correctly but same error

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, loopback

Windows Server 2008, I have setup my newest dns servers dns but it's still giving me an error stating that I don't have a loopback!
This server is 192.168.1.9

primary 192.168.1.10
seconday 192.168.1.20
 and 127.0.0.1
In that order.

This server is a domain controller as well. 
I refreshed the dns screen and re ran scan (best practices) but still get same error!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What is this server's IP address? If it is 192.168.1.10, that counts as being a loop back according to the best practice rule. If so, you'd want .20 as the first entry instead.

Also, have you made sure to download the latest BPA definitions?

Some info that might help:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff807362(WS.10).aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/08/02/new-dns-and-ad-ds-bpa-s-released-or-the-most-accurate-list-of-dns-recommendations-you-will-ever-find-from-microsoft.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments

Hope that helps.